Determinant of a similarity matrix
I have a set of vectors, and a pairwise similarity matrix defined like:
$$
K_{ij} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\|x_i - x_j\|^2}
$$
Where each $x$ is a vector.
I want to know if there is any interpretation of the determinant of $K$.
There is something called Cayley-Menger determinant, which is concerned with a distance matrix instead of a similarity matrix (distance matrix has 0s across the diagonal, but similarity matrix has 1s). Is there something related to similarity matrices? What volume is $det(K)$ computing?
